# Understanding ADFS Login With Windows Native WPF Client

Tags: c#, node.js, wpf, single-sign-on, adfs

I've read through lots of the literature on ADFS integration with NodeJS/Angular or another front end web framework and how that general flow works (and built a proof of concept through Auth0 - Angular starter code), but I'm not understanding how this would work with a native WPF Windows application?

With browser based clients (and NodeJS backend), the user is redirected to their ADFS login page in the browser and then is authenticated with SAML.

With a WPF client (and NodeJS backend), there is no browser. Additionally, isn't the user already authenticated to their Windows account? Would the WPF application have to open up an internal browser to do this authentication (seems a little "jank" to me)? Or is there a easier way to do it? How do other enterprise native Windows applications achieve this seemless ADFS SSO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Native, you use the ADAL libraries (which use OpenID Connect).

Don't use SAML as this requires browser redirects which as you have identified is tricky in WPF.

There's a good example [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/) but note this uses ADFS 3.0.

In ADFS 4.0, this is all built into the wizard.

Comment: Thank you, but at a higher level, how does this authentication happen on the NodeJS side? I am trying to integrate a WPF application with a NodeJS backend. I don't see a way for the client to communicate the authentication to the backend?

Comment: @rbrayb - Which wizard?  I'm basically attempting to ADD WindowsAuth via WebAbi/ADFS to an existing API.