# Authenticating a Cloud NodeJS Backend With WPF Client with Active Directory ADFS

Tags: c#, node.js, wpf, saml, adfs

I've asked a similar question in the past: [Understanding ADFS Login With Windows Native WPF Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53356555/understanding-adfs-login-with-windows-native-wpf-client) and I seem to have a better understanding of how to authenticate with activity directory ADFS on a WPF Native Windows application (I can use ADAL libraries), but I'm still out of the loop on how I would transfer that authentication to a remote server (NodeJS server)

I've also discovered I can do something like this in order for the native WPF application to find what user is currently logged on, and by using this, the WPF knows that the user is legit since they're logged on to their Windows account.

`var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, DOMAINNAME);
var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, Environment.UserName);`

But, I don't know how I can transfer this authentication to our remote NodeJS server (no UI, the WPF application is the UI). I can send our remote application details like, the samAccountName is `this`, but anyone can send to our remote server and claim their samAccountName is `this`. The WPF knows the user is legit, but our NodeJS application can't verify that. If I add a private certificate to our WPF application for our NodeJS server to verify, the WPF application could be decompiled to get the cert. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Can we use JWTs on the WPF side? We create all of JWTs on the NodeJs side currently

Comment: No client cannot issue JWT token to server, as a practice it is authentication token, issued by server to identify its client.

Comment: Got it. That makes perfect sense. Though would it make sense for the Windows Server to issue a JWT through ADFS and pass that to the WPF application which in turn passes it to our remote NodeJS application (and the NodeJS application has the ADFS's signing public key to decrypt it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are considering authentication in wrong context. e.g. as Node server provide you services, so each client should identify himself to Node server in order to consume Node services. 
In your implementation, you are authenticating wpf from AD, which is ok, but WPF app acts as a client to Node server, therefore there should be another authentication to provide claim that valid wpf client is connected to server.

Now come to the point, you want to authenticate WPF client + Node server from AD.In this case, actually you are authenticating both apps from some source i.e. AD. To do this you need some middle ware, which can validate both apps.

The answer to this situation is Microsoft Identity Server. Please visit some tutorial, hopefully it will solve your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your response! To add on looking at these tutorials, would this require us to have an additional asp.net server? Our WPF currently doesn't have an associated asp.net server and communicates solely with our NodeJS application. Also, do you happen to know links to any good tutorials for Microsoft Identity Server that would be helpful? I know at this point, I'm supposed do my research, but preliminary links all only show asp.net examples. Thanks again!!

Comment: Hello Thomas. I don't have any experience on nodejs. I found one article for you. can you check it
https://codeburst.io/building-a-simple-single-sign-on-sso-server-and-solution-from-scratch-in-node-js-ea6ee5fdf340